# Karman Vortex Street phenomena to turn mechanical energy into electric energy at nano to mm scale?

Tags: renewable-energy

How can one determine mathematically if it is practical to use the Karman Vortex Street phenomena at a nano scale or mm level to harness the wind's mechanical energy via a carbon nano tubular structure coupled with a magnetic system to create electric energy?

Apparently this is being tried at a macro / Meter level as referenced by the following link http://www.gizmag.com/vortex-bladeless-wind-turbine-generator/37563/
Is it practical based on the mathematics to think we can drive this system down to the nano scale or mm level?

Comment: For your first question, are you counting computational models as mathematical? For your second, that seems to be fairly opinion-based (which is generally considered off-topic), so you may want to consider rephrasing it.

Comment: Sure if a computational model works for you, great. And I have reworded second questions to make it more scientific based.